# Image not showing in TabBarIcon

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just try to add image to TabBarIcon with code below:

```js
<Tabs.Navigator>
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='Home'
                component={Home}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                        <Image
                            source={require('../assets/icons/home.png')}
                            resizeMode='contain'
                            style={{
                                width: 25,
                                height: 25
                            }}
                        />
                    }
                }}
            />
        </Tabs.Navigator>
```

Please help me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your return syntax is wrong here.
replace {} with ();
`{return (<Image/>);}` shorthand version is:  `(<Image/>)`
1st option is must when you need to do something before render,
2nd option is good when you don't need to do anything, just render

```js
<Tabs.Navigator>
  <Tabs.Screen
      name='Home'
      component={Home}
      options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
              <Image
                  source={require('../assets/icons/home.png')}
                  resizeMode='contain'
                  style={{
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25
                  }}
              />
          )
      }}
  />
</Tabs.Navigator>
```